# Why does the borrow checker care if my function uses something that it's not returning?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the function:

```
fn check_path(name : &String) -> bool {
    let path = Path::new("container_folder").join(Path::new(&name)).as_path();
    path.exists()
}
```

I am simply returning a `bool`. However, when I try to compile this, the compiler references `Path::new("container_folder").join(Path::new(&name))` and says that the `borrowed value does not live long enough`.

Why?

Shouldn't the borrow checker not care if the path is being popped off the stack since I'm not actually referencing it outside of the function?

EDIT:

If this is a duplicate, please explain how.

Comment: The compiler could indeed try and introduce temporaries as needed, but that can be quite fragile... Rust tends to prefer erring on the side of explicitness regarding lifetimes.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What temporaries need to be made? How should I explicitly define a lifetime in this case?

Comment: If you look at what [`join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join) does, it returns a `PathBuf`. You then borrow from `PathBuf` with `as_path` which creates a reference into `PathBuf`, but `PathBuf` here is a temporary (a value not bound to any variable) which disappears at the semi-colon, so that `path` would refer into a non-existing buffer. I advise you to read the duplicate, it has the same problem with `as_slice` instead of `as_path`.

Comment: I did read the duplicate, but it was not clear that they were similar problems. It's hard to see any similarity as a new user. That is the correct answer however. I had the function return `Path::new("container_folder").join(Path::new(&name)).as_path().exists()` and it compiled fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, understanding ownership is a significant challenge the first time you're exposed to it; the good news is that it becomes easier once you grok it. Here `PathBuf` is a value and `Path` is a reference; you (generally) cannot reference a value that is not named, so an easy fix is `let path_buf = Path::new("container_folder").join(Path::new(&name)); path_buf.as_path().exists();`. The "generally" is that Rust allows creating unnamed values, aka temporaries, however they get cleaned up at the end of the expression/statement. Thus your solution: using a single expression to extend the lifetime.